# Formatting multiple elements properly HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Working on a project right now creating a bet page that I just can't get to format properly. I have tried encasing everything in its own div and putting those elements into a flex-container but when I do, everything seems to get thrown on-top of each other.

Im currently trying to get everything between the breaks into their own rows with 4 separate columns.

Any insight as to what I should look into using to get this formatted properly?

It is probably worth nothing that any JS is a little out of the scope of this project.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style>
  #chuckPage
  {
   margin:auto;
   height: 50%;
   width: 50%;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: white;
   padding: 25px;
   border: 5px solid #ac5353;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  body
  {
   background-color: #59a659;
  }
 </style>
 <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Chuck-A-Luck</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="chuckPage">
   <h1>Choose your bets!</h1>
   <h2>Current Purse: $1,000.00</h2>
   <form action="Die" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="singleDie"> Single 
    <label>Die Select </label>
    <select name="dieSelect">
     <option value ="1">1</option>
     <option value ='2'>2</option>
     <option value ='3'>3</option>
     <option value ='4'>4</option>
     <option value ='5'>5</option>
     <option value ='6'>6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="singleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
    <p>1 Correct Die, 1:1, 2 Correct Dice, 2:1, 3 Correct Dice, 12:1</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tripleDie"> Triple  
    <p>Any of the triples</p>
    <input type="number" name="tripleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
    <p>30:1</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bigDie"> Big 
    <p>Sum of dice is 11 or higher (Doesn't work on triples)</p>
    <input type="number" name="bigBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
    <p>1:1</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="smallDie"> Small 
    <p>Sum of dice is 10 or lower (Doesn't work on triples)</p>
    <input type="number" name="smallBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
    <p>1:1</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fieldDie"> Field 
    <p>Sum of dice is outside of or 8 and 12</p>
    <input type="number" name="fieldBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
    <p>1:1</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" name="sendData" value="Place Your Bet!">
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example I was given to work towards.

[Click me to see the example i was given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M7UH.png)

Comment: You should check [HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are definitely a viable way to go—but let's consider `flexbox`. With a little tweaking in the `HTML`, we can create rows and columns and add responsiveness. Adding responsiveness with `table`s is possible, but not a pleasant developer experience.

In the following example, I set up the `flex` row columns to assume `25%` of available row space. When the screen is smaller than `750px`, there's no room for 4 columns of data and I change the column width to `50%`.

Make sure to test in *Full page* mode.

```css
#chuckPage {
  margin: auto;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #ac5353;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #59a659;
}

form[action="Die"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

form[action="Die"] .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

form[action="Die"] .col {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  form[action="Die"] .col {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="chuckPage">
  <h1>Choose your bets!</h1>
  <h2>Current Purse: $1,000.00</h2>
  <form action="Die" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="singleDie"> Single
        <label>Die Select </label>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <select name="dieSelect">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
          <option value='4'>4</option>
          <option value='5'>5</option>
          <option value='6'>6</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" name="singleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>1 Correct Die, 1:1, 2 Correct Dice, 2:1, 3 Correct Dice, 12:1</p>
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tripleDie"> Triple
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>Any of the triples</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" name="tripleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>30:1</p>
        <br><br>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tripleDie"> Triple
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>Any of the triples</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" name="tripleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>30:1</p>
        <br><br>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tripleDie"> Triple
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>Any of the triples</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" name="tripleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>30:1</p>
        <br><br>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tripleDie"> Triple
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>Any of the triples</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" name="tripleBetAmt" value="0" min="0" max="1000.0">
      </div>

      <div class="col">
        <p>30:1</p>
        <br><br>
      </div>

    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the table and the flex for practice and ended up liking the flex solution much better. I believe the issue I had was I was incorrectly using a <div> outside of the form. 

Thank you for your solution, a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result page to look same as the sample image, you can explore [Table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) tag and specify every item in rows and columns of the table respectively.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the answer I am looking for.